# Inverse TypeScript Type Guard

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

I am using `typescript` *2.0.0* with `--strictNullChecks` and the following type guard:

```
function isNotOk(value: any): value is null | undefined {
  if (typeof value === 'number') {
    return !isFinite(value);
  } else {
    return value === null || value === undefined;
  }
}
```

Which invalidates `null`, `undefined`, `NaN` and `Infinite`. I want an inverse of this:

```
export function isOk(value: any): value is not null | undefined {
  return !isNotOk(value);
}
```

Of course, this syntax does not work. Is there a known way to accomplish this?

Comment: do you have strict null checking turned on?

Comment: Yes, `strictNullChecks` is enabled. I'll update the question to clarify.

Comment: Why won't {return (typeof value === 'number') ? isFinite (value) : (value !== null && value !== undefined);} work? Is there a problem with the null checks?

Comment: can you explain your usecase? there might be a better way to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I stumbled upon the answer; generics. Just narrow in a reverse manner as such:

```
function isOk<T>(value: T | null | undefined): value is T {
  return !isNotOk(value);
}
```

Comment: Only issue is if `T` is `any` - then the `else` part of the type guard thinks that `value` is `never`, but it should really be `null | undefined`.

Comment: I wanted to make a notNil function and ended up just using !isNil everywhere because notNil is too complex to implement without the existence of an 'is not' keyword in TypeScript